# What name should gRPC messages have to avoid conflicts with internal classes?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a class Book and its information needs to be passed on gRPC.

```
message Book {
    ...
}
```

But if I use this name there will be conflicts between one class and the other. Is there a convention on this? What name for I use for the gRPC equivalents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any meaningful and consistent name will be fine. This problem is not specific to protobuf/gRPC. Often times, we will have an entity class called `Book` and the corresponding DTO (data transfer object) `BookDto` with more or less same fields. We add the `Dto` to the entity class name to create `BookDto`.

- This protobuf messages are basically these DTOs. You can follow the same.
- You can use the Book name and access via the qualified path to avoid the conflict. You know this and I hope you do not like it.
- Is it really a Book object? It might be a `BookSearchRequest` to query some books and you might expect `BookSearchResponse` from your gRPC service.

Comment: It's a Book object because multiple requests share it. So there might be a BookSearchRequest and a ListAllBooks and a WriteBook for example. Thanks for the tips!